# Clone HTML and convert to string

Tags: jquery

I need to clone HTML, convert to string and then convert back to object and put into html code.

```
var box = $('#box div').clone();    
var htmlString = JSON.stringify(box);
$('#box-new').html(JSON.parse(htmlString));
```

But there is an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined

What is wrong?

**Additional information:**

The main problem: I need to modify object and save to database.

```
$(selects).each(function(i) {
    var select = this;          
    $(box).find('select').eq(i).val($(select).val());
}); 


var htmlFinal = $(box).html();
//Save htmlFinal to database

//Get htmlFinal from database and print as html
$('#box-new').html(htmlFinal);
```

Everything is logical, but it doesn't work, "htmlFinal = $(box).html()" lost my selected values. I need to put cloned object directly into .html().

Comment: Firstly, this is a *really* weird thing to be doing. Secondly, `box` is a jQuery element, not a HTML string as you seem to be expecting, so that's the cause of the problem. Just use `...clone().html()`, then converting to JSON and back becomes redundant.

Comment: I'd suggest providing a runnable example to help people trying to answer this one :).

Comment: Could you give some more details about why you need to do this as I can guarantee you there's a better method to use.

Comment: What are the contents of `$('#box div')`?

Comment: @ComputerLocus you can extrapolate the HTML from the jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Lm6uhb3o/

Comment: @Manav who cares?

Comment: Can I just say it's very strange to me that you're trying to **JSON** stringify an **DOM** element...

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` will convert `box` to a string, but not to HTML:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify($("#box div")));
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div>x</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To get the HTML of the clone, use either `html` (to get inner HTML) or `[0].outerHTML` (to get outer HTML). There's also no reason for `JSON.stringify` unless you really want JSON.

```
var htmlString = $('#box div').clone()[0].outerHTML;
$('#box-new').html(htmlString);
```

For that matter, if you're getting the HTML, there's no need to `clone`:

```
var htmlString = $('#box div')[0].outerHTML;
$('#box-new').html(htmlString);
```

If there are multiple `div` elements within `#box`, that will only do the first one. We'd need to know more about your structure to know how to deal with it if there is more than one, not least because the jQuery object resulting from `$('#box div')` may have multiple `div` elements in it that have different parent elements (or are even inside other `div`s also in the same jQuery object).

---

If your goal is just to put the clone elsewhere, there's no need to make a round-trip through HTML:

```
$('#box-new').html($('#box div').clone());
```

Comment: If just want to copy `$('#box div')` but as HTML string then:- `$('<div>').html($('#box div').clone()).html()`.

Comment: @RohitSharma - Why use HTML? It's completely unnecessary.

Comment: This was just for getting HTML string like:- `const htmlOfDiv = $('<div>').html($('#box div').clone()).html()`..! As the OP wants:- **I need to clone HTML, convert to string**

Comment: @RohitSharma - With apologies, that statement doesn't make sense. When you're dealing with JavaScript code, HTML is **by definition** a string. HTML is a **textual** thing. HTML != DOM elements. Please read the above carefully. If you want HTML (a string), it tells you how to get that (no need to clone anything). If you want to append a clone of some elements elsewhere in the document, it tells you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery i would try with:

```
var box = $('#box div').clone();    
var htmlString = box.html();
$('#box-new').html(htmlString);
```

the [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) JQuery method returns a string

or the shorter version:

```
$('#box-new').html($('#box div').clone().html());
```

since Jquery methods are chainable

**EDIT**:

as Rohit Sharma pointed out the JQuery .html() method accept even a JQuery object as argument so you can directly pass the result from .clone() method to it:

```
$('#box-new').html($('#box div').clone());
```

Comment: I think, `$('#box div').clone()` does not require `html()` method after it to just update the HTML of an element..! As we can directly use:- `$('#box-new').html($('#box div').clone());`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cloning you could just grab the outerHTML directly.

```
$('#box-new').html( $('#box div').prop('outerHTML') );
```

`html()` will grab the `innerHTML` of the elements, which would not include the element selected itself.  `outerHTML` *does* include the element that was selected.